# Externalize a setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

An Angular component is using this function:

```
  resetComponent(){
    this.show = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.show = true
     }, 0);
  }
```

I would like to use this function in multiple components, as a 'util'. But when I try to use it the component variable is not bounded with the external function.

I have tried:

utils.js

```
const resetComponent = (show) => {
    show = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      show = true
    }, 0);
}
```

component.ts

```
import {resetComponent} from './util.ts'

 ...

resetComponent()
resetComponent(this.show)
resetComponent(this.show).bind(this)
this.show = resetComponent(this.show)
```

Comment: Something doesn't look right here. To control a variable that is also reflected in your component, you could pass an object since they are *usually* passed by reference. But there are better ways to control a boolean than to set a hard coded `setTimeout()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in util.ts

```
 export const resetComponent = function() {
   this.show = false;
   setTimeout(() => {
     this.show = true
   }, 0);
 }
```

In component

```
import {resetComponent} from './util.ts'

this.resetComponent.bind(this)();
```

Comment: show is undefined. It is not working neither with: resetComponent.bind(this)(this.show);